# Broadcom BCM5787M stopped working as of the update I did today

Tags: wireless

I've been on this for like the last six hours, trying to figure out how to turn my wifi back on.

I updated today, now the wifi light is always orange (off).

I've been trying to install the bcmwl kernel all night.

When I type in lspci it shows: 84:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
Which I'm assuming is the wireless adapter.

So what's the deal? I'm getting so frustrated by Linux that I'm ready to go back to Windows.

It worked this afternoon.

It worked up until I downloaded whatever this latest update is. If I knew how to tell you what the update was, I'd paste it here.

Comment: Ok, stuff I've been doing:
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source 
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

That first line does nothing, just a carriage return in the terminal. Should it not be doing that?

Getting to the last line gives me this:
(continued in next post)

Comment: ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my HP laptop, the wireless stopped working after an update. I think all I did to fix it was install the driver again because in the update they stop supporting most broadcom drivers, so you need to revert back to an older version. I'm not sure if this is any help, but it is what I concluded after 5 hours of searching the web trying to fix my internet connection. Try searching in google your device model number (broadcom BCM5787M). And make sure if you're using wireless, download the wireless driver, not the Ethernet driver.

If you don't have to update the drivers, search for a key that disables/enables the wireless on your device, the update might have switched it off, so a simple press of the key may help.

If all else fails, you can either continue to search the web for an answer, or just reinstall ubuntu and don't update everything, just update a few things (don't ask how, because I don't know) and that may help.

Comment: Annnnd I left it alone for an hour or so, when I turned it on, blue lights and wifi.

I'm utterly confounded by this. I'd like to know what happened so I can fix it again next time, rather than pounding at it like a clueless monkey, aping instructions given by those with more insight than he.